# Inject html from Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm trying to add an html string to the view from a different action (ideally from an event).

I have an action that redirects to a different url.

```
return Redirect(redirectUrl);
```

I've tried adding to the content and registering as a script:

```
_orchardServices.WorkContext.Layout.Content.Add(htmlString);

_resourceManager.Invoke().RegisterFootScript(htmlString);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A controller should not be in the business of generating HTML. That would be a view. I don't know why you think you need to do that, but it may be that you need to question your premises.